# How can i place one input radio for each item of my list?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to put one input radio to select the items of my list in php or codeigniter.

```
<ul>                    
 <?php

    foreach($modalities_actors as $mod_act){
    echo "<li>";
        echo "<input type='radio'>$mod_amu</input>";
    echo "</li>";
}
?>

</ul>
```

Comment: :S it didnt add my code.

Comment: <ul>
      
      <?php
      
      foreach($modalities_actors as $mod_act){
       echo "<li>";
       echo "<input type='radio'>$mod_amu</input>";
       echo "</li>";
      }
      ?>
               
     </ul>

Comment: You can edit your question

Comment: <input type="radio" name="abcd" value="<?php echo $mod_amu; ?>" />

Comment: Try keeping the code in the question following the instructions of posting an answer

Comment: What is `$mod_amu`?

Comment: I need to put one input radio to select the items of my list in php or codeigniter.

    Model function.
public function getModalities1($modality_id=1)
 {
  $result = $this->db
            ->select("t.id, t.title")
            ->from(self::TABLE.' AS t')
            ->where("t.modality_id = 1")
            ->order_by("t.title")
            ->get()
   ->result();

  $data = array();
  if(count($result) > 0)
  {
   foreach($result as $r)
   {
    $data[$r->id] = $r->title;
   }
  [}
  return $data;
 }

Comment: Controller.
$this->data['modalities_actors'] = $this->Modality_model->getModalities(Modality_model::ID_ACTORS);

Comment: View.


<div id="list1" style="display: block;">
    
<ul>
      
 <?php
      
  foreach($modalities_actors as $mod_act){
   echo "<li>";
   echo "<input type='radio'>$mod_act</input>";
       echo "</li>";
      }
      ?>
               
     </ul>
     
    </div>

Comment: can i add one image to show you the output?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. It is really unclear what your actual _problem_ is here. You keep telling us what you “need to do”, but what the actual issue is, you didn’t explain properly anywhere.

Comment: okay i think i got it but now i can see the list mark and the input radio mark, how can i display none the list mark? This is the typical list of categories where you can select some to submit

Answer (score 0):

Right here is code of a combo box that get's the value from database table id.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `pregunta_multi` WHERE 1 ORDER BY pregunta_multi.Id_preg_multi";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
 echo "<label class='col-xs-3 control-label'>Id_preg_multi</label>";
    echo "<div class=styled-select blue semi-square>";   
 echo "<select class='js_inline_input' name='Id_preg_multi' for='Id_preg_multi' >";


           while ( $row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<option id='Id_preg_multi' name='Id_preg_multi' value='".$row['Id_preg_multi']."'>".$row['Id_preg_multi']."</option>";
}
        echo "</select>";
   echo "</div>";

} }  

mysqli_close($link);
```

combo box example

[image]

Code Radio Button

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sqlm)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

       }

        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "Nada no DB";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

echo "<div class='tbl-header'>";
  echo "<table class='bordered' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";
        echo "<thead>";
                echo "<tr>";

                echo "<th width=900px>Pergunta #1</th>";


            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</thead>";
echo "</table>";



if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

         echo "<div class='tbl-content'>";
        echo "<table class='table'>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td width=700px bgcolor='#e6e6e6'>". $row['Descricao']. "<br><br></td>";
    echo "<form class=form-horizontal method=post >";

?>  

 <?php 
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=Nota1 name=Nota1 value='".$row['Nota']."' >";

       echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=Id_papsignup name=Id_papsignup value='".$userRow['Id']."' >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=Id_teste name=Id_teste value=2 >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=Nota_final name=Nota_final value=0 >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=rad name=rad value=0 >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=rad2 name=rad2 value=0 >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=rad3 name=rad3 value=0 >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=rad4 name=rad4 value=0 >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=rad5 name=rad5 value=0 >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=rad6 name=rad6 value=0 >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=rad7 name=rad7 value=0 >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=rad8 name=rad8 value=0 >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=rad9 name=rad9 value=0 >";
echo "<input type=hidden class=form-control id=rad10 name=rad10 value=0 >";
 ?> 
<?php 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=100px bgcolor='#f4f4f4'><input type=radio name=rad value=". $row['Nome']. " /><input type=hidden  id=Nome1 name=Nome1 value='".$row['Nome']."' >". $row['Nome']. "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=100px bgcolor='#f4f4f4'><input type=radio name=rad value=5 /><input type=hidden  id=Nomi1 name=Nomi1 value='".$row['Nome1']."' >". $row['Nome1']. "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=100px bgcolor='#f4f4f4'><input type=radio name=rad value=50 /><input type=hidden  id=Nomo1 name=Nomo1 value='".$row['Nome2']."' >". $row['Nome2']. "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=100px bgcolor='#f4f4f4'><input type=radio name=rad value=10 /><input type=hidden  id=Nomu1 name=Nomu1 value='".$row['Nome3']."' >". $row['Nome3']. "</td>";
           echo "</tr>";


            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
         echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        // Close result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "Nada no DB";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

radio button example

[image]

Comment: <ul>
      
      <?php
      
      foreach($modalities_actors as $mod_act){
       echo "<li>";
       echo "<input type='radio'>$mod_act</input>";
       echo "</li>";
      }
      ?>
               
     </ul>

Comment: <ul>
      
 <?php
      
  foreach($modalities_actors as $mod_act){
          echo "<li>";
   echo "<input type='radio'>$mod_act</input>";
   echo "</li>";
  }
 ?>
               
</ul>

Comment: echo "<tr>";
echo "<td'><input type=radio name=rad value=". $row['mod_act']. " /><input type=hidden  id=mod_act name=mod_act value='".$row['mod_act']."' >". $row['mod_act']. "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";

Comment: if you are using a database it could be like this

Comment: when i did it, i had to do a radio button for each one of them